# jQuery: Why does it create two list items from one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

I have been trying to create a list within a specific div using jQuery that should be working as a menu that links to certain recipes within the page. Hence, the list is determined on the recipes in the html. 
I have managed to create the id for each recipe and managed to create the list and the links. However, in the list the code creates two

for each recipes and I have tried everything I can think about to fix it.

Here is the html code (I have not included everything due to the length):

```
<div id="primarycontent">
            <div class="post">
                <h4>
                    Potatis.
                </h4>
                <div class="contentarea">
                    <p>
                        ...
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="post">
                <h4>
                    Potatisbullar.
                </h4>
                <div class="contentarea">
                    <p>
                        ...
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="post">
                <h4>
                    Potatismos
                </h4>
                <div class="contentarea">
                    <p>
                        ...
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(generateMenu);
$(document).ready(addIdRecept);    

function generateMenu() 
{
var menyList = $("<ul></ul>");
$("#receptmeny").append(menyList);

$(".post h4:first-child").each(function(i)
{
    var txt = $(this).closest(".post").find("h4").text();
    var li = $("<li><li/>")
    .appendTo(menyList);
    var aLink = $("<a></a>")
    .attr("href","#recept" + i)
    .text(txt)
    .appendTo(li); 
});
}

function addIdRecept()
{
    $(".post h4").each(function(i) 
    {
        $(this).attr("id", "recept" + i);
    });
}
```

This creates this list:

- Potatis
- Potatis
- Potatisbullar
- Potatisbullar
- Potatismos
- Potatismos

Why does it create two list items??

Comment: Why did you unselect my answer? I had given that same answer earlier!  May I know the reason?

Comment: I thought I could select two answer as both you and Davy gave the same answer. Sorry my mistake, I will change back to your answer as you gave it first. (I am new here so still learning how it all works)

Comment: OK,  no issues! All the best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(generateMenu);
            $(document).ready(addIdRecept);

            function generateMenu() {
                var menyList = $("<ul></ul>");
                $("#receptmeny").append(menyList);

                $(".post h4:first-child").each(function (i) {
                    txt = $(this).closest(".post").find("h4").text();
                    var li = $("<li></li>").appendTo(menyList);
                    var aLink = $("<a></a>").attr("href", "#recept" + i).text(txt).appendTo(li);
                });
            }

            function addIdRecept() {
                $(".post h4").each(function (i) {
                    $(this).attr("id", "recept" + i);
                });
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="primarycontent">
        <div class="post">
            <h4>
                Potatis.
            </h4>
            <div class="contentarea">
                <p>
                    
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="post">
            <h4>
                Potatisbullar.
            </h4>
            <div class="contentarea">
                <p>
                    
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="post">
            <h4>
                Potatismos
            </h4>
            <div class="contentarea">
                <p>
                    
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    <div id="receptmeny">
```

The reason is this line:

```
var li = $("<li><li/>").appendTo(menyList);
```

Modify the line to:

```
var li = $("<li></li>").appendTo(menyList);
```

Notice you are adding `/` after li instead of before it.

Comment: @MikaelLennholm Try the sample code, it doesn't. Atleast on chrome!

Comment: when I changed to </li> it worked perfect, at least on safari

Comment: @xarroo That means it works both on Chrome and Safari. Why did you unselect my answer and selected another user's answer which is exactly same as mine?

Comment: @PankajShukla I thought I could select two answer as both you and Davy gave the same answer. Sorry my mistake, I will change back to your answer as you gave it first. (I am new here so still learning how it all works)

Comment: @PankajShukla There's no part of the sample code that uses `$("<li/>")`. `<li/>` is just a shorthand for `<li></li>` in jQuery and it works perfectly fine in Chrome

Comment: @MikaelLennholm Look at the part `var li = $("<li><li/>")
    .appendTo(menyList);`. Did you try running the code? What do you see?

Comment: @PankajShukla Of course `$("<li><li/>")` doesn't work, that was the whole issue. But `$("<li/>")` DOES work, it's just a shorter version of `$("<li></li>")`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the funny and tricky question. 
Please check the second line of jquery first function - `var li = $("<li><li/>")`

This should be - `var li = $("<li></li>")`
Then it will generate as you want.

Good luck